# Read email content when type is text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I am reading unread emails from a specific folder like this. Message content type is coming as **text/html; charset=iso-8859-1** . How can I get the content as a string ? When I do a toString I am getting something like this com.sun.mail.util.QPDecoderStream@4461c7e3

```
  public Message[] fetchMessages(String host, String user, String password,String folder, boolean read) throws IOException {
            try {
                Properties properties = new Properties();
                properties.put("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");

                Session emailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
                Store store = emailSession.getStore();
                store.connect(host, user, password);

                Folder folderToRead = store.getFolder(folder);
                folderToRead.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
                Flags seen = new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN);
                FlagTerm unseenFlagTerm = new FlagTerm(seen, read);
                Message messages[] = folderToRead.search(unseenFlagTerm);
                System.out.println(messages.length);
                for(Message message : messages){
                    System.out.println(getMessageContent(message));
                }
    }
public getMessageContent(Message message){
        String result = "";
        if (message.isMimeType("text/html")) {
           // My message type is coming as text/html
            result = message.getContent().toString();
        }
        else if (message.isMimeType("text/plain")) {
            result = message.getContent().toString();
        } 
        return result;

}
```

Comment: Where does `Message` come from? Did you read its documentation?

Comment: Its a plain text message in my outlook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

text/plain is an unknown type and was coming as an inputstream. This worked for me

```
private static String getTextFromMessage(Message message) throws IOException, MessagingException {
        String result = "";
       if (message.isMimeType("text/plain")) {
            result = message.getContent().toString();
        } else if (message.isMimeType("multipart/*")) {
            MimeMultipart mimeMultipart = (MimeMultipart) message.getContent();
            result = getTextFromMimeMultipart(mimeMultipart);
        }
        else{
             StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
             IOUtils.copy(message.getInputStream(), writer, "UTF-8");
             result = writer.toString();
        }
        return result;
    }
```